# Symfony JsonResponse: Fetching each element of multidimensional array returned by symfony controller

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, symfony

basically what I am trying to do is trying to fetch each element from the array of "arrays" passed by symfony controller when I try to fetch all the rows of the table. my controller is working absolutely fine, and giving me output:

> [{"id":1,"name":"johnsonn's baby shampoo","dsc":"shampoo","pic":"572f8a02d59b3.jpg","company":4,"type":"baby products","price":150,"sold":null,"stock":200},{"id":2,"name":"johnson's soap","dsc":"baby soap","pic":"57303fc35f72c.jpg","company":4,"type":"baby products","price":52,"sold":null,"stock":1000}]

and my javascript for fetching this output is the following:

```
<script>
    function fetchprod() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/show/prod",
            dataType: "json"
        }).success(function(data){
            $('#container').html(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    }
    fetchprod();
    setInterval(function () {fetchprod()}, 3000);
</script>
```

what I wanna do is fetch each element of each array separately so that I can place create a div out of them so they could be arranged in a grid properly.

also the array is fetched by symfony controller (if you need an extra info):

```
public function showAction($slug){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    if($slug == 'prod'){
        $repo = $em->getRepository('SystemBundle:Products');
        $q = $repo->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();
        return new JsonResponse($q);
    }

}
```

Comment: Some notices: it is an array of objects. Your showAction in Symfony must return a response, even if the value of `$slug` is not 'prod'. Return an exception or something appropriate after the if clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, maybe you could use the `each` method:

```
// ajax call
.success( function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        var div = '<div>' + JSON.stringify(value) + '</div>';
        $('#container').append(div);
    });
});
// close function
```

In this way you iterate over every object in the array, place it in a div, and after that append it to the `#container`.

It should create something like:

```
<div id="container">
    <div>{"id":1,"name":"johnsonn's baby shampoo","dsc":"shampoo","pic":"572f8a02d59b3.jpg","company":4,"type":"baby products","price":150,"sold":null,"stock":200}</div>
    <div>{"id":2,"name":"johnson's soap","dsc":"baby soap","pic":"57303fc35f72c.jpg","company":4,"type":"baby products","price":52,"sold":null,"stock":1000}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot, and one more doubt, everything is perfect but every 3 seconds when the function is called, the same elements keep adding itself again and again (due to append)... how to prevent that, (I replaced append with .html() but just pastes 1 value)

Comment: found it, I empty the container everytime the function calls, thanks a lot, worked great for me! :)